# How extensive is the belief in consensus truth?

Tags: truth, subjectivity

Consider the following propositions, reflecting a certain individualist perspective on truth and consensus:

- When a person believes something, they may be wrong.
- When a whole society agrees on a consensus position, it is possible for them all to be wrong.
- It is possible for an individual to be right and a group to be wrong.
- An individual who is by himself remains capable of thinking meaningfully, even if he is alone for a very long time.
- An individual learns of the existence of inanimate objects in the world only through empirical investigation via his senses.  This investigation is fallible.
- An individual learns of the existence and speech of others only through empirical investigation via his senses.  This investigation is just as fallible as empirical investigation of inanimate objects.
- If there is a social consensus, the individual learns of it only through empirical investigation through his senses, which is fallible.
- Individuals have private mental lives that are meaningful to them, although others may not learn of them.
- For every proposition P, it is the work of the individual to decide if he believes P or not.  He may rely on the advice of others but ultimately the decision to believe it occurs in his own brain.
- Just because one doesn't know something doesn't mean it isn't true.
- Just because a group doesn't know something doesn't mean it isn't true.

My question is this:  How prevalent is disagreement with these claims, and how seriously is it taken?

Comment: There are a lot of claims, do you mean disagreement with at least one of them? Could you indicate what sort of disagreement you have in mind more specifically, most of them look like platitudes. Some sort of non-empirical infallible knowledge?

Comment: @Conifold yes, disagreement with at least one of them.  I'd consider them all things that everyone should take for granted, and yet, I've come across a number of people who apparently wouldn't agree with many of them.  I'm interested to learn whether this disagreement is an extreme minority position or if it has some level of mainstream acceptance.

Comment: @Conifold for example, I've heard claims that truth (not just knowledge) is socially constructed, or that what we don't know doesn't matter and isn't part of our reality, or that what is not socially expressed in language is irrelevant or even not able to be assigned a meaning.

Comment: The way this q is phrased ("how prevalent", "how extensive") seem to be about social psychology rather than philosophy.

Comment: @Fizz I mean how prevalent among philosophers. I wouldn't imagine any person uninvolved in philosophy would disagree with any of the claims as they are intuitively obvious, a "default position."